# Не работает переключение текста по клику

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть скрипт, который по клику присваивает селектору класс `.active` и меняет текст его дочернего элемента:

```
$('.ticket-show-more').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $(this).find('span').text('Свернуть');
});
```

И есть скрипт, который теоретически должен работать по клику на этот же селектор с классом `.active`, но почему-то не работает и текст обратно не меняется:

```
$('.ticket-show-more.active').on('click', function(){
    $(this).find('span').text('Подробнее');
});
```

Как это исправить?

Comment: потому что обработчик навешивается **только** на те элемент у которых **уже есть** класс active

Comment: @Grundy тогда как можно изменять текст в блоке по клику и возвращать обратно, по типу toggle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('a.ticket-show-more').on('click', function() {
  var active = $(this).toggleClass('active').hasClass('active');
  $('span', this).text(active ? 'Свернуть' : 'Подробнее');
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="ticket-show-more">
  <span>Подробнее</span>
</a>
```